# a tkinter program error i cant seem to get rid of

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-layout

I am getting an error using tkinter and I cannot understand what I am doing incorrectly to cause this error.

**Here is my code:**

```py
from tkinter import *

windows = Tk()
frame = Frame(windows,height = 200 ,width  = 700)
heading = Label(frame,text="COST CALCULATOR").grid(row = 0,column = 1,columnspan =7)
frame.pack()

def area(length,breadth):
    global area
    ftom(length,breadth)
    area = length*breadth
    return area

t1 = Label(frame,text = "enter the length:").grid(row = 1 ,column = 0)
e1 = Entry(frame)
e1.grid(row =1,column = 1)
ln = e1.get()
e1.delete(0,END)

t2 = Label(frame,text = "enter the breadth:").grid(row = 2 ,column = 0)
e2 = Entry(frame)
e2.grid(row = 2,column = 1)
br = e2.get()
e2.delete(0,END)

t3 = Label(frame,text = "total area covered").grid(row = 3 ,column = 0)
ln = int(ln)
br = int(br)
ar = area(ln,br)
e3 = Label(frame,text =f"{ar}")
e3.grid(row = 3 , column = 1)
windows.mainloop()
```

**And this is the error I get:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Allen Alex Abraham/allensworld/allensworld/trial2.py", line 55, in <module>
    ln = int(ln)
ValueError: **invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''**
```

Comment: The error is telling you that you're trying to convert an empty string to an integer, which obviously isn't possible. `ln` is not what you're assuming it is because you're getting it a millisecond after creating the entry widget, well before the user has a chance to type anything.

Comment: `Entry()` doesn't work like `input()` - it doesn't wait for user's data so `.get()` gives you empty string - use `Button()` to run code which gets data from `Entry`

Comment: You will need to place your `get()` code inside the function and then add a button that calls that function.

Comment: Hey, a few words of explanation for your question would be nice to have. There might be others with the same problem. Copy/paste from code and the compiler output is not considered to be a valid question.

Comment: what is the `ftom` you are using in the function?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're calling `e1.get()` about a millisecond after you create the entry widget, well before the user has a chance to input data.

GUI programming is not like non-GUI programming - widgets don't block until the user enters something the way that `input` does. Instead, you need to define a button or some other way for the user to perform the calculation when they are ready (menu item, keyboard binding, etc).

The simplest solution is to create a button to perform the calculation. When you click the button, the function tied to the button can gather the data it needs, call a function to compute the result, and then update the display with the results.

For example, start by defining a function that will get the data and compute the result:

```
def do_calculation():
    length = int(e1.get())
    breadth = int(e2.get())
    result = area(length, breadth)
    e3.configure(text=result)
```

Next, create a button that will call this function when clicked:

```
do_calc_button = Button(frame, command=do_calculation, text="Calculate")
do_calc_button.grid(row=4, column=0)
```

With that, the user can enter values, click the button, and see the result.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply, you cleared many of the confusions I had.

Answer (score 0):

Your code and issue is easier enough to fix. That said you really need to add a description of your problem. It may not be clear to everyone what your issue is just based on code alone. It is considered a bad question and will likely be down-voted and get lest help like it is now.

That said I would change a few things here.

1. do `import tkinter as tk` instead if importing * as this will help prevent overwriting of methods down the road.
2. Your `get()` methods are executed the instant your code initiates so to fix this problem you need to move them into a function and then call that function with a button or a bind after something has been added to your entry fields.
3. `get()` always returns a string so your math wont work until you convert your values to integers or floats. so something like `int(e1.get())` will work here. That said to prevent errors when something other than a number is submitted you can use a `try/except` statement to handle errors.
4. do not name functions and variables the same thing. This can cause problems so always have uniquer names for your variables/functions/class and so on.

Take a look at the below code and let me know if you have any questions:

```
import tkinter as tk


windows = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(windows, height=200, width=700)
tk.Label(frame, text="COST CALCULATOR").grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=7)
frame.pack()

tk.Label(frame, text="enter the length:").grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Label(frame, text="enter the breadth:").grid(row=2, column=0)
tk.Label(frame, text="total area covered").grid(row=3, column=0)
e1 = tk.Entry(frame)
e2 = tk.Entry(frame)
e3 = tk.Label(frame, text=f"")
e1.grid(row=1, column=1)
e2.grid(row=2, column=1)
e3.grid(row=3, column=1)


def area_func():
    ln = e1.get()
    br = e2.get()
    e1.delete(0, "end")
    e2.delete(0, "end")
    try:
        area = int(ln) * int(br)
        e3.config(text=f"{area}")
    except BaseException as e:
        print("Value error. Make sure you have only entered a valid integer.")
        print(e)


tk.Button(frame, text="Submit", command=area_func).grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)
windows.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you so much for the reply cleared out many confusions I had. just started out using stack overflow and that's why my question is really poorly structured/asked.